# Passing formula to aggregate

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I want to calculate groupby stats for multiple variables in a `data.frame`.

I understand you can do this:

```
aggregate(cbind(Ozone, Temp) ~ Month, data=airquality, mean)
```

But how do I make it more general? That is, instead of specifying the variable names explicitly like `cbind(Ozone, Temp)`, I want to do (for example)

```
aggregate(names(airquality)[1:10] ~ Month, data=airquality, mean)
```

which does not work since `names(airquality)[1:10]` would be a vector of strings.

How would I do this? I tried to generate a formula with `as.formula` and `paste` but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can work from another perspective and just change the "`data`" argument:

```
aggregate(. ~ Month, data = airquality[, c("Ozone", "Temp", "Month")], mean)
#   Month    Ozone     Temp
# 1     5 23.61538 66.73077
# 2     6 29.44444 78.22222
# 3     7 59.11538 83.88462
# 4     8 59.96154 83.96154
# 5     9 31.44828 76.89655

aggregate(. ~ Month, data = airquality[, c(1, 4, 5)], mean)
#   Month    Ozone     Temp
# 1     5 23.61538 66.73077
# 2     6 29.44444 78.22222
# 3     7 59.11538 83.88462
# 4     8 59.96154 83.96154
# 5     9 31.44828 76.89655
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way.

```
df <- data.frame(group=rep(1:5,each=10),x=rnorm(100),y=rnorm(100),z=rnorm(100))
aggregate(df[,c("x","y","z")],by=list(df$group),mean)
#   Group.1           x           y             z
# 1       1 -0.06100408  0.04669238  0.0003988935
# 2       2  0.03195340 -0.04475700  0.1851086065
# 3       3 -0.19219404 -0.01944643  0.4282583083
# 4       4  0.22507825 -0.43640489 -0.3980140143
# 5       5  0.35749140  0.38679963 -0.2421865009
```

This does the same thing.

```
aggregate(df[,2:4],by=list(df$group),mean)
```

Comment: This pretty much explicitly *ignores* the formula method, which is what I think they are trying to use...